# jQuery fadeIn with different image on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get a different image to fadeIn in the same place but on *different pages*. So, for example, my #header is a DIV tag and I placed a #logo DIV tag within it to hold my logo image (that I want to fadeIn).

Now I can get a different image to load in the #logo DIV on each page with CSS by giving the body tag for each page an ID - but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get jQuery to fadeIn these images.

This is where I am hoping better minds than mine can help me figure this out.

I know a little about html and CSS and very little about programming and jQuery. I am trying to get through the Javascript &jQuery Missing Manual book, but it hasn't been a huge help thus far.

Appreciate any help.

Below is what I have in my code (such as it is). I can't figure out how to "select" the images I want to use and then apply the fadeIn function to them.

Sorry but I wasn't allowed to upload a picture yet, heres all I have so far - it isn't much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="_CSS/siteWide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="_jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
$('#index #logo').fadeIn(4000); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<body id="index"><!--/*allows for different images in different headers--> 
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContent">
  </div>
  <div id="sideBar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="politics.html">Politics</a></li>
      <li><a href="Religion.html">Religion</a></li>
      <li><a href="Health.html">Health</a></li>
      <li><a href="Things That Bug Me.html">Bug me</a></li>
      <li><a href="Other.html">other</a></li>
    </ul>    
  </div>

  <div id="footer">Content for  id "footer" Goes Here</div>
Content for  id "wrapper" Goes Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

so you have a different index set for each page, which will link to a certain image. below I have your index element having an 'id' attribute. so for example on page1 you will set the index element like so:

```
<div id="index" pageId="first"></div>
```

and for the second page:

```
<div id="index" pageId="second"></div>
```

etc etc. in your HTML. then your javascript is like so:

```
var yourPageId = $('#index').attr('pageId');

$('#logo').hide();

switch(yourpageId){
case "first":
  $('#logo').attr('src',"images/yourFirstImage.jpg");
  break;
case "second":
  $('#logo').attr('src',"images/yourSecondImage.jpg");
  break;
default:
  alert("Uh Oh ID is not set or matched);
}

$('#logo').fadeIn();
```

Make sure in this case that your #logo element is an img element:

```
<img id="logo" src="" />
```

or else if you have it set up like:

```
  <div id="logo"> <img /> </div>
```

then you will have to adjust for which element is setting the source and which element you want to fade In

Comment: Hi Evan, Thanks but I need specific images on specific pages. The array idea sounds like it would work but how to call the array for each page? I gave each page a body ID (ie"index", "contacts" etc, so that I could then use ID tags (#index #logo) to add a different image in the same spot on different pages. Now I just need to get them to fade In.

Comment: oops sorry i forgot the fadeIn...you should be able to do the edited above

Comment: oh i think I see what you mean. i am redoing my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is some code I used recently in a project. If you don't care what image loads on what page and just have a bunch of random images, you can try something like this:

Html:

```
<div class="visual">
   <img src="..." style="display: none;/> 
   <img src="..." style="display: none;/> 
   <img src="..." style="display: none;/> 
</div>
```

Then you can use this jQuery to have one of these images fade in randomly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var size= $('.visual').find('img').length;
   var counter=Math.floor(Math.random()*size);
   $('.visual').find('img').eq(counter).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

If you just want to fade an image in you've already got working with your code / css you should try using the `fadeIn()` function.

```
$('#logo').fadeIn('1000'); //the number is how long it takes to fade in...
```

Note that you will want to have `#logo{ display: none; }` set in your css.

Comment: Hi mkprogramming, Man, I don't understand this forum yet - can't add a return. Anyway I can get 1 image to do the fadeIn - but getting more than 1 and on a different webpage is where I am having the problem. I like your random script - but I need specific images on specific pages - which is why I gave each page a body ID.

Comment: Tony,
Is there a reason why you can't just use `$('#logo').fadeIn();` ? That way you can have `#index #logo` styled differently from `#other #logo` but still fade in? (I mentioned that at the bottom of my answer)